# Swift: recognize when UITextField is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift and have been stuck on this for hours. I am trying to recognize when a UITextField is tapped by the user, and call some function. For some reason I keep getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance". 
Here is my attempt at a solution
[image]
and
Here is the error thrown 
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code segments in the thread, it will be easier to see that way.

Comment: Copy/Paste code, do not post screenshot only.

Comment: What Bawpotter means is not put code in an image. Please put code in using the code tools in the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is not pointing to the method! Try this instead:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapped(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
```

Also, instead of this approach you could also set `ViewController` as the delegate for `textField` and implement this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("tapped")
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `action: #selector(ViewController.tapped())`

Also, below that, add this: `self.textField.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply perform you action in UITexFieldDelegate,
by making

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

and use the method

```
optional public func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
//perform you action here
return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of finding a way to get tap event you can use textFieldDidBeginEditing function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
 print("TextField did begin editing method called")
 }
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
 print("TextField did end editing method called")
 }

}
```